# Getting Old UI when reloading App for First time in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am very beginner in flutter development so have very little knowledge about its working but need to clear my doubt.

I had created an app using flutter create  command and a sample flutter project directory is created. When I opened the app using visual studio code and run the app over the physical device an app is created in my device and showing the basic increment counter feature on the screen which is due to the code written in main.dart file.

I remove all the content of main.dart file and wrote my code there and reload it. The app is working fine.

The problem is everytime when I connect my device with my computer I am getting the UI of the sample project created initially and only after reloading again I am getting my new UI.

This problem only exists when first time I am connecting my mobile for debugging and after reloading it is resolved.

Why I am getting the old UI (the one with counter generate while created app for the first time) even though there is no code regarding the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of bug. I also faced the same problem and finally i fixed it using ***flutter clean*** from the terminal. Hope you also already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using hot reload only. Stop the app from the IDE and rebuild. Then after restarting the emulator will be no problem.

Comment: I am running on the physical device and tried the same for that too

Comment: Then try to upgrade flutter to the latest version.